# Python Conda install old version of matplotlib keyerror linux3

Tags: python, matplotlib, conda

While trying to install the tool PrimerProspector from the development version (SVN trunk, as instructed here: http://pprospector.sourceforge.net/install/install.html) I tried creating a conda environment to resolve the dependencies in an elegant way (I am running an Ubuntu server 16.04.3 LTS machine with conda 4.4.8). The PyCogent and Numpy can easily be installed in the required version using `pip install` when the environment (with python 2.6) is activated.  I have conda forge in my channels. However, when running `pip install matplotlib==0.98.5.3` I run into the issue that there is no such version available (`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matplotlib==0.98.5.3 (from versions: 0.86, 0.86.1, 0.86.2, 0.91.0, 0.91.1, 1.0.1, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.4.0, 1.4.1rc1, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 2.0.0b1, 2.0.0b2, 2.0.0b3, 2.0.0b4, 2.0.0rc1, 2.0.0rc2, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.1.0rc1, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2)`). Additionally I get an InsecurePlatformWarning which is apparently common with an older Python distribution. Nevertheless, as the source was available I tried using `pip` to install from the [tarball](https://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-0.98.5/). This gives me the rather uninformative `KeyError: 'linux3'`:

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ============================================================================
    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
                matplotlib: 0.98.5.3
                    python: 2.6.9 | packaged by conda-forge | (unknown, Apr 29
                            2017, 15:44:38)  [GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat
                            4.8.2-15)]
                  platform: linux3

    REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-7ZwjL5-build/setup.py", line 99, in <module>
        if not check_for_numpy():
      File "setupext.py", line 497, in check_for_numpy
        add_base_flags(module)
      File "setupext.py", line 319, in add_base_flags
        [os.path.join(p, 'include') for p in basedir[sys.platform] ])
    KeyError: 'linux3'

    ----------------------------------------
```

Directly running setup.py after untarring also renders the same error. Does anyone know how to resolve this? Is there anything I can do to find out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mathplotlib version you're trying to use has been released years before the release of Linux 3.0. That's why it has no support for `sys.platform='linux3'`. And the Python version you're using is older than 2.7.2, which dropped setting the `linux3` value.

You can try to just edit the `setupext.py` file in the tarball, and in the dict `basedir` add config for `linux3`, which would be the same as for `linux` and `linux2`.

Comment: Thanks, that appears to have worked, at least until I got a different error related to probably also an issue with the compatibility of the TCL/TK in the OS. 
But now I need where to look so as soon as I can I will award you the bounty.